# Landsat TOA TI and Landsat TOA T2

Tags: landsat

I want to know the difference about TOA T1 and T2. Are they two repeating collections?  I want to use the imagecollection (merge from Landsat TOA T1 and T2).
How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Landsat website:

*'The Collection definition consists of three categories: Tier 1, Tier 2, and Real-Time. Data in Tier 1 meet formal geometric and radiometric quality criteria. Tier 2 do not meet the Tier 1 criteria. The Real-Time Tier contains data immediately after acquisitions that use estimated parameters. Real-Time data are reprocessed and assessed for inclusion into Tier 1 or Tier 2 as soon as final parameters are available.'*

You can read more here: https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-collections?qt-science_support_page_related_con=2#qt-science_support_page_related_con

you can try to use google earth engine to access and analyze any Landsat collection that you wish.